# Is it normal that get_post() gets run 300 times and the content of those posts aren't visible?

Tags: wp-query, get-post

Is it normal that `get_post()` gets run 300 times and the content of those posts aren't visible? Ran Query Monitor and saw get_post() from wp_query getting run 300 times, but it's on my homepage and I don't see the content of those posts since most of the content of the homepage are statically generated and don't get their content from posts. Is it possible that get_post gets run even when we don't need it? How do we find the culprit and get rid of those unnecessary calls? I found the count on Queries By Caller and I don't see a way to find where they're all getting called.

Comment: this is highly unusual

Comment: Do you know what might be causing this? I didn't have time to investigate further, so I just want to know what to look for.

Comment: if you have query monitor then that tool can already tell you a lot of information about who/what is running the query, and it'll try to guess the plugin/theme responsible, there isn't much I could tell you that Query Monitor doesn't already do

Comment: Is there a way to get the stack trace of every call?

Comment: yes, on my site there's a + button that expands into a stack trace in the caller column of the queries page, I suspect this might require your server to have xdebug installed though. usually you can guess from the query itself who's responsible or from the component column which tries to place the blame. Also I thought you said `get_postS` I misread your question, `get_post` shouldn't make DB calls though, usually it grabs the data from cache